# Apache Jclouds BlobStore getBlob with GetOptions

Tags: java, jclouds

Anyone knows how to get blob from blob store with `GetOptions`:

```
BlobStore blobStore = context.getBlobStore();
Blob blob = blobStore.getBlob(cloudStorageContainer, fileName);
```

what I wanted to achieve is to pass the ETag value to the `org.jclouds.blobstore.options.GetOptions` when calling `BlobStore.getBlob()` methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jclouds can conditionally get a blob based on its ETag via one of:

```
BlobStore.getBlob(containerName, blobName, new Getoptions().ifETagMatches(etag));
BlobStore.getBlob(containerName, blobName, new Getoptions().ifETagDoesntMatch(etag));
```

Comment: Can you share the example on how to pass the parameters